# Output order display wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I getting a very weird issue. I have a hashmap list (groupList) in `FragemtA`. Everytime `fragmentA` is run, it should call `checkUser` function, and finally get the return value display at the `forEach` there.

```
    var id = ""

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            val userId = checkUser()

            activity.groupedList.forEach {
                for (i in it.value) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "user id in groupedList" + userId)
                }
        }

fun checkUser(): String {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val response = WebApi.getOrganizationsList(activity)
            if (response?.status == "success") {
                id = response?.user_id.toString()
                Log.d(TAG,"id in checkUser "+id)
            } else {
                longToast("FAIL")
            }
        }
        return id
    }
```

Why I will get this output ?

```
D/xxx: user id in groupedList
D/xxx: user id in groupedList
D/xxx: id in checkUser 46
```

I would expect `id in checkUser 46` display first, but it not !

**Desired output**

```
D/xxx: id in checkUser 46
D/xxx: user id in groupedList 46
D/xxx: user id in groupedList 46
```

Comment: It that was the case you will be blocking the UI Thread, right ?

Comment: @Blackbelt you mean on the `checkUser` function ?

Comment: right that one.

Comment: @Blackbelt How I can I fix it? I need to get the id from server using coroutine

Comment: What do you mean? You are already getting the id using coroutine

Comment: @Blackbelt I have edited my post which desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are launching a thread but not waiting on it's completion. Change it to wait and you will be fine. BTW, Using GlobalScope is typically discouraged. You should consider implementing CoroutineScope on your class so that you can simply use the keyword "launch".

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val userId = checkUser()

            activity.groupedList.forEach {
                for (i in it.value) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "user id in groupedList" + userId)
                }
        }
    }

suspend fun checkUser(): String = suspendCoroutine { c->
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            var id = ""
            val response = WebApi.getOrganizationsList(activity)
            if (response?.status == "success") {
                id = response?.user_id.toString()
                Log.d(TAG,"id in checkUser "+id)
            } else {
                longToast("FAIL")
            }
            c.resume(id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: no problem, happy to help, but like i mentioned, consider going away from GlobalScope, that leaves room for memory leaks to occur.

Answer (score 1):

First, your coroutine doesn't need to return a string because you are already saving its result in the property `id`.

Second, the message you are expecting to be the first one is the last one because the coroutine that you are launching finishes executing later than the loop – by the time the `forEach` loop is run, the coroutine hasn't finished yet. You have to keep in mind that you code will not execute sequentially because you are not awaiting for the coroutine to finish.

One option is to perform your action (i.e., the `forEach` loop) inside the coroutine once you are sure the ID value has already been retrieved successfully:

```
fun checkUser() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val response = WebApi.getOrganizationsList(activity)
        if (response?.status == "success") {
            id = response?.user_id.toString()
            Log.d(TAG,"id in checkUser "+id)
            activity.groupedList.forEach {
                for (i in it.value) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "user id in groupedList" + id)
                }
            }
        } else {
            longToast("FAIL")
        }
    }
}
```